# Tool to Dynamically Edit CSS

Tags: css

I recall hearing about a tool that allows you to **dynamically edit CSS when viewing a page.** This is primarily useful for developers, and I'm not looking to apply those changes later.

Does this tool exist? I'm looking for something that works with either FireFox or Chrome.

Comment: Sounds like you want Firebug =D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Firefox: [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com).
- Chrome: dev tools are built in:

[image]

[image]

Comment: How do you use it in Chrome? I can't seem to edit any properties. For example, I want to change the height of an element; I'm already in Inspect Element and viewing the source and properties.

Comment: View > Developer > Developer Tools. Click on node, and you will see the element styles on the right window.

Comment: @ashes: see my edit. Double-click the property name or value that you want to change in the `Styles` pane.

Answer (score 0):

This is the firebug extension for Firefox !

http://getfirebug.com/

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can edit css dynamically with Firebug addon for Firefox. You can do the same with the latest version of Opera (is built in) and also I imagine Chrome too.

Infact with these tools you can edit not just css but html and the rendered DOM too. Plus you can run js too.